# Reorganize within a chest in MCPE

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

I'm playing Minecraft Pocket Edition on my old iPad, but I'm wondering if there is a way to organize stuff *within* a chest. I'm not asking about how to categorize the different chests, but how to reorganize stuff *within a given chest*.

I.e. within a `Stone` chest, I would like for the `Cobblestone` to be in a given row, or possible to move to a given row, and the `Gravel` to be elsewhere. Similarly for tools I would like to group the `Pickaxe`'s, `Sword`'s, and so on.

I know I can use other random items as fillers, but that is really tedious work, and I would much rather have a way to move from one block/space within the chest to another block/space in the same chest. Preferably without having to intermediately store it in the inventory.

<sub>My version of MCPE is 0.14.3 on iOs, and if answers are version related please state, if known, which version the answer applies to or from.</sub>

Comment: There is no way to automatically organize your items within a chest. I recommend making lines on your own and dragging and dropping. If you want to be really organized, you could use full chests of items and use hoppers to put them there.

Answer (score 0):

Since 1.0 (I believe), the new "classic" inventory (in the video section of the settings) allows for people to drag items around in chests.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and easy way to organize in rows, yet it only works with stack-able blocks:

[image: a opened minecraft chest showing blocks organized in rows]

The player in the image above has sorted the blocks into rows and placed one of that same block in each empty space of the row. This allows the player to quick move any blocks he wants to add to the chest without worrying about them becoming disorganized.